# Sci-fi book series with a spaceship below the ice in Antarctica

Tags: story-identification, books

I don't remember much from the book, but what I do remember is this:

1. Humans are the only sapient species in the universe (to their knowledge)
2. Humans on earth have been watched over by other homo sapiens, these being from a different world. Kind of like how you would build a vivarium  to study an ecosystem
3. The scientistis studying the early humans have been trying to find other sapient life in the universe, but to no luck. They are able to sleep in cryopods so they can study the evolution of species through thousands of years
4. The is a space ship below the ice in Antarctica, and time there is different than time outside of it
5. The protagonist is female, and I remember her accidentally using a teleporter inside of the spaceship, going to a distant star where a battle happend hundreds of years before.

Comment: Just to mention -- I'm pretty sure that the book in question is **not** *Stranger Suns* by George Zebrowski,. That starts out with a team exploring a huge spaceship that's been found embedded in the ice in Antarctica, but then the plot goes in a whole different direction. I don't think humans were "immigrants to Earth" in that one, and I don't remember any Nazis getting involved. By the way: Should we take it that this story was set during the historical period when Adolf Hitler was the ruler of Nazi Germany? (Or perhaps in an alternate timeline where the Axis powers had already won WWII?)

Comment: Some elements of what you describe are present in David Weber's 'Mutineer's Moon', specifically humans being descendants of aliens stranded on Earth, alien spacecraft in the 'bad guys' base under the Antarctic ice, and one of the main characters being female. I don't think there's any Nazi presence though.

Comment: Mabye there was no nazis within the book, but I do remember that someone exploring the spaceship was, I believe, one the the bad guys within the book. Reading the synopsis of the books none of them reminded me of it. I can also remember that the scientists of the ancient spaceship where able to use cryopods, and follow the evolution the the human race on earth. And that also one of the scientists was responsible for setting a volcano to blow.

Comment: Another thing I can remember was that using teleporters on the ship, the protagonist was able to travel to a battlefield around a star far from our own. I believe that the battle took place long before there where homosapiens on earth

Answer (score 5):

It's a pretty recent publication so I'm hesitant to bring up "The Atlantis Gene" by A.G. Riddle but yeah this is definitely it.

I won't confirm all your points due to spoilers, but there is definitely some alien stuff happening under ice in Antarctica. And there is a cool history of human-like travelers watching the Earth through mankind's early history.

Cryopods, teleporters, ancient battles, yup.

Comment: Please do add the spoilers!  You can hide them using `>!` but they may be important for the OP to recognize this as a correct answer.

Comment: Thanks DavidW. I haven't been on here in a while. Forgot what the syntax was. However the volcano comment in the original post is a dead giveaway for this book.

Comment: There are lots of details (in a general way) on [the goodreads page](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25843420-the-atlantis-gene), which you might link to.  Anything mentioned there is probably fair game.  I see the question no longer mentions Nazis, but they are noted in several of the reviews.

Comment: @Cradle2theGabe, it is the Atlantis gene. Reading the synopsis confirmed it. Hank you! I'm positive other readers looking for the book they are thankful too.

Comment: @user123783 Please click on the grey checkmark under the voting arrows in the upper-left corner of this answer to mark it as correct.  That will help future searchers, and give you a small additional amount of reputation.